# VS Code Protractor: Described is not defined error

Tags: node.js, protractor

I'm learning Protractor. I'm using VS Code and have a simple Protractor program. It runs fine from the command line: protractor config.js -- but -- when I try to run it from inside VS Code, by pressing F5, I get ReferenceError: describe is not defined.

What am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js'],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }
}

// spec.js
describe('Protractor Demo App', function() {
  it('should have a title', function() {
    browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');

    expect(browser.getTitle()).toEqual('Super Calculator');
  });
});

{
    // launch.json
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/spec.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some wrong configuration in your launch.json, try below one:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/protractor/built/cli.js",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "args": [
            "config.js",
        ]
    }]
}
```

`${workspaceFolder}` represents the folder VSCode opened, it expect to be your project folder.

Comment: That got it working but, I had to use this string to get it work: C:\\Users\\RalphF\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\protractor\\built\\cli.js
I'm currently working in C:\ptest and in here there is no protractor folder inside the node_modules folder. I guess that means I didn't install protractor in this ptest folder?

Comment: you are right, you should add protractor as your project dependency.  when others to run your script, he can get all dependencies installed by execute 'npm install' under project folder,  so you no need to tell others 'you need to install protractor in advance', anyone should can learn your project dependencies from package.json's dependencies field.  execute 'npm install -S protractor' under project folder, you will get it installed and added into package.json's  dependencies field

Comment: I ran npm install -S protractor from my main folder. Then I switched back in the jason file to "program": "${workspaceFolder}/spec.js" to see if my original line would work -- but -- VSC said I needed to npm install -g jshint but that said module.js:450 throw err "Cannot find module C:\Edge\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js. Should I just stay with the two new lines you suggested?

Comment: 1) jshint is a tool to check javascript sytax, it's no thing with run script by protractor. I can't know why yo; u meet such issue;  2) for 'can't find module' issue, did you put your nodejs install folder (like C:\Tool\nodejs, and there shoud be a npm.cmd in that folder) to PATH environment variable. Remeber execute npm install in new CMD window.